# Execute task on Azure VM with condition

Tags: azure, ansible

I need to take down Azure VMs in a controlled way, first stopping them and then removing them. The "stop" part needs to be executed only if the VM is existing, otherwise the task creates one in a stopped state, and then removes it. I tried variations on `when: state == "present"` but without success. Where can I find an example or documentation about how I can use that? Or maybe the solution to have a previous task retrieving the VM info, and act on that?
TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't tried already, give it a try by having the first task using the module "azure_rm_virtualmachine_info" and make sure you save the result to a variable using "register" command. Then have the second task using "when" command to check if the value is "present" or not for the state object of the variable thats saved in the earlier task.

Comment: Aha! Yes, that should work! There's a lot to learn when starting with something new. Thank you!